# Django migrations - how to apply newly applied rules to previously saved model instances?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-migrations

Let's say I have the following model and I have already some instances of the model saved in the database -

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, if I want to change the `max_length` argument to `127` instead of `255` and apply the migrations, the older instances will still be in the database where some might have the length more than 127 which is not obeying the new migrations.

What is the best approach to migrate all previous data along with the new migration rules?

Comment: Why do you want to alter a table if already existing elements doesn't fit your new rules ? Even with raw SQL, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your migration and apply that before the generated migration (which alters the model).

For this purpose, you have first to write your migration. Place it in the `migrations` folder of the app. Then add its name to the `dependencies` field of the generated migration.

This example updates the `uuid` field of all `MyModel` Objects.
And is located in `my_migration.py`

```py
# Generated by Django A.B on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
from django.db import migrations
import uuid

def gen_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
    for row in MyModel.objects.all():
        row.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        row.save(update_fields=['uuid'])

class MyMigration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0004_add_uuid_field'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # omit reverse_code=... if you don't want the migration to be reversible.
        migrations.RunPython(gen_uuid, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Assume that your generated migration that alters `MyModel` is called `GeneratedMigration.`. edit the generated migrations file as below.

```py
class GeneratedMigration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', 'my_migration'),
    ]
```

You can also use the `run_before` attribute.

Checkout [djano documentation on writing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/writing-migrations/) for more information.

Comment: [Nima Afshar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10462931/nima-afshar), thanks!